# Getting "Failed to determine a suitable driver class" when upgraded to Finchley.RELEASE and Springboot 2.0.5.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I am getting "**Failed to determine a suitable driver class**" when upgraded to `Finchley.RELEASE` and `Springboot 2.0.5.RELEASE`

`BootStrap.yml` looks like

```
spring:
  application:
    name: OutboundEventEngine
  cloud:
    consul:
      config:
        enabled: true
        defaultContext: ZygrateOutboundService
        profileSeparator: '::'        
        watched: 
          enabled: true
        prefix: DEV
      host: 127.0.0.1
      port: 8500
```

> Error logs:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:126) ~[outbound-event-engine.jar:1.0.18-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:86) ~[outbound-event-engine.jar:1.0.18-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:413) ~[outbound-event-engine.jar:1.0.18-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:174) ~[outbound-event-engine.jar:1.0.18-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:179) ~[outbound-event-engine.jar:1.0.18-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:152) ~[outbound-event-engine.jar:1.0.18-SNAPSHOT]
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'healthEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthEndpoint]: Factory method 'healthEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fd6c45dc]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

It works with Dalston.SR4 and Springboot 1.5.10.RELEASE.
Thanks !!!

Comment: upvoted since it does not deserve downvote. Please provide question in post of what exactly you need help with, even if it is obviously implied. It has to be explicit.

Comment: My best guess is that some library is not loaded properly. Can you provide pom.xml? also, did you update all related libraries specified in maven of the updated library?

Comment: Is that your full app yml? It's trying to init a datasource and doesn't know what kind.

Comment: Please provide a sample app that reproduces the problem.